# How to loop OVER several arrays

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I have n number of arrays. Same amount of rows in each of them: Array0, Array1, ..., Arrayn.

Now I want to loop through all of them and ultimately join them. Transpose each Array to a column of the new created ResultArray

```
for (var ID = 0; ID < n+1; ID++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ("Array" + ID).length; i++) {
      ResultArray[i][ID] = ("Array" + ID)[i]
        }
  }
```

**Here is an example of what I want:**

```
Array0 = [Apple, Banana, Chicken]
Array1 = [5, 7, 8]
Array2 = [High, Low, Low]
ResultArray = [[Apple, 5, High], [Banana, 7, Low], [Chicken, 8, Low]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have the following arrays.

  ```
      Array0 = ["Apple", "Banana", "Chicken"];
      Array1 = [5, 7, 8];
      Array2 = ["High", "Low", "Low"];
  ```
- You want to convert above arrays to the following array.

  ```
      [["Apple",5,"High"],["Banana",7,"Low"],["Chicken",8,"Low"]]
  ```
- From your sample array, the array length of each array is the same.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script 1:

```
var Array0 = ["Apple", "Banana", "Chicken"];
var Array1 = [5, 7, 8];
var Array2 = ["High", "Low", "Low"];

var arrays = [Array0, Array1, Array2]; // Please prepare this.

var res = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arrays[0].length; i++) {
  var temp = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < arrays.length; j++) {
    var ar = arrays[j];
    temp.push(ar[i]);
  }
  res.push(temp);
}
Logger.log(res)
```

#### Modified script 2:

```
var Array0 = ["Apple", "Banana", "Chicken"];
var Array1 = [5, 7, 8];
var Array2 = ["High", "Low", "Low"];

var numberOfArrays = 3; // Please prepare this. In your case, it's 3.

var res = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Array0.length; i++) {
  var temp = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < numberOfArrays; j++) {
    var ar = eval("Array" + j);
    temp.push(ar[i]);
  }
  res.push(temp);
}
Logger.log(res)
```

#### Note:

- Please select one of above scripts for your situation.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Wonderful! :) Used 'Modified script 1' and it works perfect!

Comment: @Kibou Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this in a more concise way with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const arr1 = ["Apple", "Banana", "Chicken"], arr2 = [5, 7, 8], arr3 = ["High", "Low", "Low"],
      data = [arr1, arr2, arr3]

let result = data.reduce((acc, c) => 
 (c.forEach((x,k) => acc[k].push(x)), acc), Array.from({length: data.length}, () => []))

console.log(result)
```

Or in a more readable form:

```js
const arr1 = ["Apple", "Banana", "Chicken"], arr2 = [5, 7, 8], arr3 = ["High", "Low", "Low"],
      data = [arr1, arr2, arr3]

let result = data.reduce((acc, c) => {
  c.forEach((x,i) => acc[i].push(x))
  return acc
}, Array.from({length: data.length}, () => []))

console.log(result)
```

The idea is to `merge` those arrays and then do `Array.reduce` where the `accumulator` is already in the form of `[[],[],[]]` so we just populate each of the child arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to find the longest array. Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the longest array, and get the row index. Then use a second `Array.map()` to get the row items from the arrays.

```js
const zip = (...arrs) => arrs
  .reduce((r, c) => c.length > r.length ? c : r, []) // get the longest array
  .map((_, i) => arrs.map(a => a[i])) // map the longest array to get the current row number, then create the row

const arr1 = ["Apple", "Banana", "Chicken"], arr2 = [5, 7, 8], arr3 = ["High", "Low", "Low"]

const result = zip(arr1, arr2, arr3)

console.log(result)
```